# Is it possible to represent -3/32 as a binary floating-point value using only 7 bits

Tags: floating-point, binary

Suppose you are limited to 7 bits for a floating-point representation: 1 sign bit, 3 exponent bits, and 3 fraction bits.

First I convert `3/32` to the binary `0.00011`,
then to the standard scientific notation of `1.1 * 2^(-4)`.

At this point I realize my exponent field will be `-1`, which is not valid.
I try to represent `3/32` as `0.11 * 2^(-3)` instead, which leads to the more intuitive representation of `1 000 110`.
However, obviously this is a denormalized value, and if I try to convert the representation back to decimal I get `-3/16`.

My question is: is it even possible to represent this value precisely within the constraints of the problem?
It looks like the smallest representable value for this scheme is `-15`, so `-3/32` falls within this interval.
I'm aware that bits are dropped and precision is lost during conversions; is this the case here?

Comment: Is the exponent stored in biased form? If so, what is the bias?

Comment: @njuffa I should've been more specific. I'm not sure what "biased form" refers to, but the exponent field should be read as an unsigned binary value. The bias here is `2^(3-1)-1 = 3`, so the power we take `2` to is `-2`, because for denormalized values the exponent for `2` is calculated as `1 - bias` or `1 - 3 = -2`. During the conversion from decimal to floating-point, I calculated the value of the exponent field using the fact that `E = (exponent field) - (bias)` to conclude that `(exponent field) = E + (bias)`. Here, E is the power we raise 2 to.

Comment: If your FP format follows the IEEE convention for denormalized values, an exponent-field of `0` would mean an actual exponent of `1-bias` and a significant of `0.xxx`, i.e. `1 000 011` would be `- 2^(1-3)*0.011 = -0.00011`.

Comment: @chtz Simple oversight on my end... Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1 sign, 3 exponent, and 3 significand bits, following IEEE-754 rules, here're the first four non-negative smallest finite values you can represent:

```
Bits       | Decimal Value
-----------+----------------
0b0000000  | 0
0b0000001  | 0.03125
0b0000010  | 0.0625
0b0000011  | 0.09375
```

The value you're looking for, `3/32`, equals `0.09375` (decimal); matching the 4th value. So, it is precisely representable in this format.

Detailed representation of this value is:

```
                  6 543 210
                  S E3- S3-
   Binary layout: 0 000 011
      Hex layout: 03
       Precision: 3 exponent bits, 3 significand bits
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -2 (Subnormal, with fixed exponent value. Stored: 0, Bias: 3)
  Classification: FP_SUBNORMAL
          Binary: 0b1.1p-4
           Octal: 0o6p-6
             Hex: 0x1.8p-4
```

Since you wanted `-3/32`, you can simply set the sign bit.

Comment: You've rounded the decimal values in your table -- the actual values are 0.03125, 0.0625, and 0.09375 -- so that last one is actually exactly correct for 3/32

Comment: @ChrisDodd You're absolutely correct. Fixed the values.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to represent your number in (binary) scientific notation, which is 0b1.1×2<sup>-4</sup>.  So in general for a (normalized) floating point value, you'll have a mantissa of just `1` (padded out with trailing 0s to fill the field) and an exponent of -4

The problem is that with only 3 exponent bits, you'll (probably) have a bias of 3 (2<sup>k-1</sup>-1 for k bits), which means the minimum representable exponent is -2.  As a result, you need to use a denormalized representation with no "hidden" 1 and an exponent of -2.  So you shift the mantissa to increase the exponent to -2, giving 0b0.011×2<sup>-2</sup>.

This makes your final 7-bit fp value 0 000 011  -- sign is 0, exponent field is 0 (for a denorm) and mantissa is 011